# How to read one-row .txt dataset in R?

Tags: r

My .txt dataset looks like the following:

```
perms ['AC', 'AT', 'AG', 'AN', 'CA', 'CT', 'CG', 'CN', 'TA', 'TC', 'TG', 'TN', 'GA', 'GC', 'GT', 'GN', 'NA', 'NC', 'NT', 'NG', 'AA', 'CC', 'TT', 'GG', 'NN'] link [11413851, 16930583, 16197703, 1085, 16533859, 16218116, 2309941, 572, 14414084, 13609414, 16552907, 1015, 13594224, 10038778, 11427660, 480, 1055, 445, 1061, 591, 15557040, 9822185, 15583349, 9815249, 11653456]
```

There's two variables in this dataset: 'perms' and 'link'. How can I read this dataset in R? I cannot use brute-force, because of the exact size of my sample is just too huge (some of them have n>100 000). But the structure is totally the same. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We read the dataset with `readLines`, split by space followed by `[` or `]` followed by zero or more space.  Create a logical index ('ind'), subset the split data, loop though it, `scan` to get the individual elements, and convert to 'data.frame'.

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
lines1 <- strsplit(lines, "\\s*\\[|\\]\\s*")[[1]]
ind <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
data.frame(setNames(lapply(lines1[!ind], function(x) 
    trimws(scan(text=x, what = "", sep=",", quiet=TRUE))), lines1[ind]))
#   perms     link
#1     AC 11413851
#2     AT 16930583
#3     AG 16197703
#4     AN     1085
#5     CA 16533859
#6     CT 16218116
#7     CG  2309941
#8     CN      572
#9     TA 14414084
#10    TC 13609414
#11    TG 16552907
#12    TN     1015
#13    GA 13594224
#14    GC 10038778
#15    GT 11427660
#16    GN      480
#17    NA     1055
#18    NC      445
#19    NT     1061
#20    NG      591
#21    AA 15557040
#22    CC  9822185
#23    TT 15583349
#24    GG  9815249
#25    NN 11653456
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it works pretty well! Am I able to use this code with more variables?

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar  I guess this should also work with multiple variables, as we are using logical index.